# wget or curl throws -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: wget

I am trying to download a file which has symbol "(" in it;s URL.
I tried using wget and curl. Bash is not allowing it to be processed and throws "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('".

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the brace with a backslash?

Comment: Thank you. Escape character solved the problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should escape the character by adding a "\" before it. Like `\(` or `\)`

Answer (score 3):

Add single quotes `'` or double quotes `"` around the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone found this useful.

In my case, I want to curl this file name **data (1).rar**

then it should be write like this in the terminal

```
http://example.com/data%20\(1\).rar
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and solved that issue just by adding double quotes to the command what I am passing.
for eg:

> git checkout "<branch_name>"